# Inserting to set in a "Fixed" Size Loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, insert, iterator, set

So I wanted to insert the double of all the elements in my `set` back into the `set`. But obviously I need to grab the end iterator so that I don't keep iterating over new elements. (Don't worry, I checked, `set::insert` doesn't invalidate iterators: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/#validity) So given the input, `set<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 }`, here's what I did:

```
for(auto it = begin(foo), finish = end(foo); it != finish; ++it) {
    foo.insert(*it * 2);
}
```

I expected my set to contain:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 6

Surprise! It contains:

> -2147483648, -1073741824, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128, 192, 256, 384, 512, 768, 1024, 1536, 2048, 3072, 4096, 6144, 8192, 12288, 16384, 24576, 32768, 49152, 65536, 98304, 131072, 196608, 262144, 393216, 524288, 786432, 1048576, 1572864, 2097152, 3145728, 4194304, 6291456, 8388608, 12582912, 16777216, 25165824, 33554432, 50331648, 67108864, 100663296, 134217728, 201326592, 268435456, 402653184, 536870912, 805306368, 1073741824, 1610612736

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/hVTQMa)

Clearly `end(foo)` doesn't work as I thought it did. So... if I want to save the loops size and count to that?

Comment: looping on a container and mutating the container state at the same time is a big no no.  If the end result of the operation is going to be a container of a different size then, IMHO, you should copy the generated dated into a new container.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I was actually looking at someone else's code that did this. I was just surprised by the results.

Comment: That the end iterator isn't invalidated doesn't mean that it's still one-past-the-end of the original collection; it's now one-past-the-end of the collection in its post-insertion state.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah I was surprised cause I had mentally coupled `finish` to behaving as though it was a Random Access Iterator even though it clearly wasn't since it wasn't being invalidated by insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your assumption is that a `set` is allocated into a contiguous container with the presumption that it initially had enough space that reallocation of the contiguous container was not necessary; in this assumed case I would also expect to see your behavior. (It should be noted though that even in a situation where this were a contiguous container, the container's capacity would need to be validated for this assumption to avoid undefined behavior.)

But even in your question you  point out that `insert` doesn't invalidate iterators, which means that the container cannot be contiguous. In fact [`set`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/?kw=set):

> Are typically implemented as binary search trees

Understanding this you're really just continuing your loop till your iterator ends pointing to the last leaf node. Your compilers `set` implementation caused that to happen when you inserted the `-2147483648` element, but that's implementation dependent, and thus may behave differently on another compiler.

You're looking for a behavior that is defined and compiler independent. Depending upon you're knowledge of the set contents you could reverse iterate over the `set`:

```
for(auto it = rbegin(foo); it != rend(foo); ++it) {
    foo.insert(*it * 2);
}
```

**This is only a good solution if the insertion creates elements that are sorted *after* those being iterated over. For example if `foo` contains negative numbers this won't work.** You could evaluate this by checking: `if(*cbegin(foo) < 0)` in the `else`-block you could do the reverse iteration loop suggested above, but in the otherwise you'd need to do a temporary set allocation described in [The Quantum Physicist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41853866/2642059).

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are still valid, but as a `std::set` is a node-based container, the elements are always sorted, using `std::less<Key>` by default

See how iterators are jumping to lower values, making it to struggle for `finish`

[Code snippe](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98f6dcfc7f356d62)t:

```
    for(  ; it != finish; ++it)
    {
        auto t = *it  ;
        std::cout << "At " << t  << "\n";
        foo.insert( t * 2  ) ;
        std::cout << "Inserted " << t*2  << "\n";
    }

At 1
Inserted 2
At 2
Inserted 4           <----+
At 3                      |
Inserted 6                | <---+ 
At 4  // jumped back -----+     |
Inserted 8                      |
At 6  // Jumped back -----------+
Inserted 12
At 8
.....
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously circular. The size is increasing in every step, making the loop never reach the end.

It's like saying: Take this list, start from the first element, and keep doing this for every element, and when you're done, add one more element to the same list.

Why would this ever end?

---

EDIT:

Answering: "So... if I want to save the loops size and count to that?":

```
int size = foo.size();
std::set<int> bar;
for(auto it = begin(foo); it != end(foo); ++it) {
    bar.insert(*it * 2);
}
foo.insert(bar.begin(), bar.end());
```

Comment: "So... if I want to save the loops size and count to that?"

Comment: Nope `auto it = begin(foo), int i=0` is definitely illegal.

Comment: It compiles now, but `it != finish, i < size` is a bad idea. You probably intended the logical and operator rather than the comma operator, but in this loop all you really needed was `i < size`.

Comment: @JonathanMee I think this is the best solution now. This is safer. Check the new code. This is safer because you can't guarantee that older elements will precede newer elements. You should create another set.

Comment: Yeah, that's @Baldrickk's recommendation, and I agree it's probably the best one.

Comment: Just wanted to apologize for moving the accept. I found a better solution for the general case of this. I've added a link to your answer for the specialized case when negative numbers are present.

Answer (score 1):

A typical method of doing this would be to iterate through your source set, and perform your function on each value, adding the result into a second set.
Once you are finished with the iteration process and have fully generated the second set, union the two sets together.

Comment: This doesn't explain the issue. OP is probably not looking for alternative and probably knows a work around.

Comment: @P0W Thanks for your faith in me. That's not always well placed, though, yes, in this case it was :J

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to save the loops size and count to that, you can do something like this:

```
set<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 };

int setSize = foo.size();
auto it = foo.begin();

for(int i = 0; i < setSize; ++i) {
    foo.insert(*it * 2);
    ++it;
}

copy(cbegin(foo), cend(foo), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

This will give you the output: `1 2 3 4 6`